# FlameRobin: Not Responding While Establishing Connection

Tags: odbc, firebird, firebird2.5, flamerobin

I have installed `Firebird-2.5.6.27020_0x64` and `Firebird_ODBC_2.0.4.155_x64` in a Windows 10 64 bit computer system architecture. I have set-up also ODBC configuration in `ODBC Data Source Administrator (64 bit)` and test connection was successful.

[image]

In the FlameRobin, I have created  localhost as a `Display Name` and `Host Name` and register existing database.

[image]

When establishing connection, the FlameRobin is always not responding.

[image]

Where did I go wrong? I have already disabled my anti-virus.

Comment: Note that your ODBC connection is not connecting in the same way as flamerobin, change the ODBC database path to `localhost:<path of your db>` to get the same behavior. I would be surprised if you can connect though, as the user running Firebird server should not have access to your user folder.

Comment: Please post the server registration details of "localhost" in FlameRobin and a screenshot of port 3050 in Windows ressource monitor -> network -> listening ports